# move a long picture like it's blinking with css

Tags: html, css, animation

As you can see from the picture, it includes 6 parts.
I build a div 40px by 40px containing this picture.

```
overflow:hidden;
```

I want to animate this picture like it's blinking. which looks like: at the 1st second showing 1st part, the second showing the second part.
[Requirement: please don't make the animation like It's slide from bottom to top. ]

Here's how I did, not working.
1.using keyframe, like 20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 100%. add top:-40, -80,...;  but it looks like I'm slide the picture. 
hope someone can help me out.  Thanks a lot.

[image: 40px by 240px]

Comment: do you know about animated gifs?

Comment: Why not use `opacity` in addition to `top`?

Comment: @ronan have you tried some of solution proposed?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan yes, The first answer solved my problem. appreciate that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `steps()` function applied to a simple CSS3 background animation like so

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JoEoPL

---

**HTML**

```
<div>Acquiring signal...</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAIVQ.png);
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;

  -webkit-animation: blinksignal 6s steps(6, end) infinite;
  animation: blinksignal 6s steps(6, end) infinite;
}


@-webkit-keyframes blinksignal {
  0%   { background-position: 0 0 }
  100% { background-position: 0 -480px }
}

@keyframes blinksignal {
  0    { background-position: 0 0 }
  100% { background-position: 0 -480px }
}
```

---

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/timing-function)

> The steps() functional notation defines a step function dividing the domain of output values in **equidistant** steps. This subclass of step functions are sometimes also called staircase functions.

Answer (score 0):

Do You mean about sth like here: http://jsfiddle.net/5jpasp1v/

I've simply add 3 `div' elements with state for each state, and change it with css

HTML:

```
<div id="wifi">
    <div class="state state-1"></div>
    <div class="state state-2"></div>
    <div class="state state-3"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes blink {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.state-1 {...}
.state-2 {...}
.state-3 {...}
```